# Geometry Problem with an isosceles trapezoid

Tags: geometry

Be $ABCD$ an isosceles trapezoid with bases $AB$ and $CD$ (with $CD< AB$), $angle$ABC = 80º, $\langle$ABD = 60º. Also there is a point E $\in$ AB with $\langle$BAE=50º.

If AB = $a$, CD = $b$ and CE = $x$

$x$ = ?

Comment: You probably mean $E\in BC$.

Comment: Is it $E$ the intersection with $CD$?

Comment: Yes Aretino, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AH=\frac{a-b}{2}$

so $HB=a-\frac{a-b}{2}=\frac{a+b}{2}$

as $DBH$ is half an equilateral triangle, $BD=a+b$

and $HD=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}\,(a+b)$

so $BC=AD=\sqrt{AH^2+HD^2}=\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}$

Triangle $ABE$ is isosceles, base $AE$ so $BE=BA=a$

Therefore $x=BC-BE=\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2}-a$

Hope this helps

$$...$$

[image]